# Is there a way to make the path of $HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties different for every build?

Tags: android, gradle, github-actions

I have set build-related settings in `$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties`

Although the build process is the same, it is a situation where I have to change the setting of `$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties` for each runner of github actions because of other restrictions.

Therefore, I want to create `$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties` for each runner. Can I change the path for each runner?

(It is a structure in which several runners are installed in one machine.)

Comment: Can't you just use the GRADLE_USER_HOME env variable/command line options to point to different .gradle directories? Or is that something that you want to avoid?

Comment: I thought about that method too.
But, isn't there a problem because that variable can be shared?(environment variable)
For example, in the situation where build 1 specified for GRADLE_USER_HOME,
If I specify GRADLE_USER_HOME when build 2 is executed in parallel, is there any case that build 1 is wrong?

Comment: That is way I said: you might want to have multiple .gradle directories, like: one for each builder? How to tune your setup really depends on your other requirements.

Comment: Yes, I want to have multiple .gradle directory for each build on the same machine.
But consider the case where build 1 changes the path, and then build 2 changes the path.
For example build1 changes GRADLE_USER_HOME to $HOME/build1/~~~~
And then, build2 changes GRADLE_USER_HOME to $HOME/build2/~~~~.
In this case, when build 1 reads the variable, the value will be replaced with the value that build2 changed beacuse  they run on the same machine.
Is it right??

Comment: I cant you help much on the github/automation/runner side here. I am just in a similar situation ... we are building multiple products out of one code base - using docker containers. We recently switched the java parts of our build to gradle, and now our verification build keeps failing because the parallel docker runs keep stepping on each other.

Comment: I solved it by passing the property through the cli every build time!